# How to set the default page to show when typing this http://[instance name] on the browser?

Tags: sitecore

I delete the defualt home node and create another node called Home Page. And when I type http://[instance name] sitecore gives me an error shows that no layout found. ![enter image description here][1]

I can us the page editor and page content normally. But when i type the http://[instance name]in the browser, it doesn't show the default page. Why?
I am just a fresh in Sitecore, please be more specific.

Error:The layout for the requested document
was not found.
Most likely causes:
The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) may have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
What you can try:
  Go back to the previous page
  Go to the start page
  More information

Answer (score 4):

I usually hit this issue when I have a fresh install and haven't done a publish yet.  Publishing gets the master and web in sync, and given that your Page Editor experience is fine it seems like your Master is in good state but Web is not.

Comment: He can also test this by setting the site to Live mode - change the filename to `LiveMode.config` in `App_Config/Include`

Answer (score 2):

It could be that your new Home node doesn't have a layout attached to it. If you log on to Sitecore's Content Editor and go to the Presentation tab -> Details, do you see anything assigned to the Default device?
If you do, it might be because you still need to publish your changes. If you don't, try attaching the layouts (there's some sample layouts as well that come with Sitecore to check if that's the issue).

Answer (score 1):

Do the checks that Trayek suggests, but also check if your site definition and hostname are set correctly in the /app_config/include/sites.config (or directly in the web.config, however this it not the recommended way) to make sure you have attached the correct instancename to your site root.

Furthermore, switch in the Sitecore client to the web database and check the assigned presentation on your home item, it might be a publishing issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you have the wrong "startItem" parameter in your site configuration? You have to set it to the correct item that should be visible wenn entered without an url (/)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should check the Web.Config  configuration tag.

Please check, in there, there are startitem attibutes for various sites in there. change them to your startItem and try it out.

Hope this helps!

Do let us know -- whether it works or not.

Regards,

Varun Shringarpure